# MomentJS on Angular to keep changing value on realtime

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I have an array of objects that has a property called `startedTimestamp`. I need to show on the front-end how long ago that has been running, on this case I'm using **MomentJS** with the `fromNow()` method. However, that will not updating as the time goes by... to something like *1 minutes ago*... and then *2 minutes ago*... and so on. Is there a way around that?

I'm using Angular.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recreate an angular scenario here but it seems [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) will do the trick. It's important to create the moment object just once (outside `setInterval`) then the label's text will be updated every second.

Run the code and wait at least a minute and you'll see how it changes from 'a few seconds ago' to 'a minute ago'

```js
const label = document.querySelector('label'),
span = document.querySelector('span');

const m = moment();
let secondsPast = 0;
setInterval(()=>{
  span.textContent = `${++secondsPast} seconds past`
  label.textContent = `${m.fromNow()} from ${m.format()}`
},1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<span></span><br><br>
<label></label>
```